# How to prerender single page app that uses React?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, prerender

In my application, users have their own profile page in which there is their profile picture (I'm using react router to deal with routes on client side).

What I want to do is: when a user sends link to his profile on messenger/slack/twitter then the thumbnail of the link should be his profile photo.

I know that I need to do this by sending correct meta tag, i.e.
`<meta property="og:image" content="url-image.jpg">`

But I am not sure how to implement this, what should I know about it? I found a thing called prerender, but I am not sure if it's for React

Comment: Try this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-meta-tags

Comment: Prerender.io works great with React! :D https://prerender.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a little research, I think the only why to do this is by server side rendering. It looks like Facebook doesn't care about loading JavaScript and won't detect a change in the `<head>` section. I checked this by building a simple React application that sets the OG data in the `componentWillMount()` section. The [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/) could not find the headers.

So the answer on your question depends really on the kind of back-end you are using. You need to set the meta data before you send the response to the client.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you may want to use [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet#server-usage). It's a document head manager and supports server-rendering.